# How could I put the condition lines in between the equations in a equ-set?

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image: Example pic]

I want to put the condition in the equation set in this way, the current script doesn't work:

```
$ 
y_v=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1,$ if v was received and decodable, $ & \forall v \in V \\
0, $otherwise $
\end{aligned}
\right.
$
```

[image: current pic]

Any idea how to make the position correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You looking for `cases` environment. Available in `amsmath` and `mathtools` environment.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\[
y_v=\begin{cases*}
1,   &  if $v$ was received and decodable, \\
0,   &  otherwise
\end{cases*}
\quad   \forall v \in V 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you are loading the `mathtools` package, why do you use the `cases` environment with two `\text{...}` commands inside?  Just use `cases*` instead.

Comment: yeah, now I don't understand myself :-(, corrected now. thank you very mucth for pointing on this.

Comment: Have I your permission to post an almost identical answer that shows how I would handle this case?  **Edit:** Now I’ve seen the edit on your comment, so please ignore this reply. :-)

Comment: Of course! Specially if you will provide some explanation. Todaj I'm lazy for writing English texts ... :)

Comment: No, as I’ve just said, with your recent edit your answer is now fine.  (+1)